# "Failed to start session" for main and guest accounts

Tags: login, lightdm

I was updating my Ubuntu LTS and we had a power outage. Now, when I try to "sign in", I get a "failed to start session" message in bold red under my main and guest accounts. I'm not sure how to fix this.

I'm also unable to connect to the Internet. I have tried (Ethernet, WiFi, and Hotspot)

When I try signing in with the wrong password on the main log-in screen, it says "invalid password", but when I use the correct password it says failed to start the session when I try to sign in using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> it says login incorrect.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217895&page=2  See comment 12.  Go to a virtual terminal (ctrl-alt-F2) login, then sudo apt-get install

Comment: I keep getting log in incorrect when trying that  I know I am not getting them wrong though

Comment: When I try signing in with the wrong password on the main log in screen it says invalid password but when I use the right password it says failed to start session when I try to sign in using (ctrl-alt-f2) it says login incorrect

Comment: Double-check the num-lock key (and caps lock).  When on, a laptop may have an overlayed keyboard for some letters.

Comment: Yeah I had tried that I also tried different variations of the password but have had no luck

Comment: This may be a silly question but is there a way to revert to a previous state?

Answer (score 0):

You can try an older kernel, under the "Advanced ..." grub menu choice.  It might help to run fsck from an install media on the root partition.  Try booting in single user mode, by adding the word "single" after the "quiet splash" on the linux line in the grub boot commands. At the grub menu, type "e" to edit (instructions at bottom of screen), add the word, and then type ctl-x or F10 to boot.  In single user mode, you should be able to try the apt-get install commands to let things complete.  Mid-way thought an update, it's pretty hard to unwind back to a previous state -- I've never tried it, but ...  If you can get past the login hurdle, you can fix things easiest by letting the update proceed.

Another thought, try a/another USB keyboard if you have one around. Run the memory check if grub offers that choice.  After a power failure, who knows what hardware may be fried.

Answer (score 0):

After you login with the graphical interface, does it transition to a black screen, and cycle you back to the login?  If so, try booting into single user, navigating to your /home directory.  Try:

```
cp .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak && rm .Xauthority && sudo reboot
```

This will regenerate a new .Xauthority file at login

Comment: OP says exactly what happens and not that it's a login loop. You should say what you mean by "single user" (recovery mode?) and exactly how to get into it. But I don't think this is OP's problem and if it it's a duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](//askubuntu.com/q/223501)